# To Create a Table in AdventureWorks in existing Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create `Employee2` table in `adventureworks` database. However when I create a table using graphic interface and save it then it has the prefix `dbo` and saved as `dbo.Employee2`.

I wish to save the table in `HumanResources` schema as it will be saved as `HumanResources.Employee2`.
How to do this?!!

Comment: You need to use **select * into HumanResources.Employee2 from dbo.Employee**

Comment: Here is the answer - you need to open table properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489872/how-do-i-create-a-sql-table-under-a-different-schema

Comment: If you press F4 (options window) in SSMS you are able to change the schema in the options window as per @fly_ua 's link

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'HumanResources ')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [HumanResources] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END

ALTER SCHEMA HumanResources
    TRANSFER dbo.Employee2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand you want to create a Table Employee2 in a defined schema HumanResources of adventureworks sample Db.

So going with GUI Go to New Table then define your Employee2 columns and datatypes etc then on Properties windows at right side of screen choose your schema HumanResources and save it. Thats it.