# SQL server: To create a table inside a schema

Tags: sql-server

I wish to create a table T1. And when I execute the query that table should be include in `HumanResources` schema which already exists in the database.

How should I change my query to do this? To get table `T1` into the `HumanResources` schema?

```
Create Table T1
(
    Id  int,
    Name varchar(20)
)
```

Comment: **RTFM:** [this is the official MSDN documentation on `CREATE TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) which explains this **In great detail** .....

Answer (score 6):

```
Create Table HumanResources.T1 (...);
```

In your attempt, you are trying to add it to a database called `HumanResources` and to the schema `dbo`. It's *database.schema.object.*

### Edit

In response to the OP's comment, the question has already been answered here: [How do I create a SQL table under a different schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489872/how-do-i-create-a-sql-table-under-a-different-schema)

Comment: If I am creating the table using Graphic Interface, where can I find the option to select the schema?

Comment: @Gt_R You should add that information to your question. No one's going to assume you're doing it that way since you included the script statement.

Comment: I understand that. Your first answer was something that I really needed and was very helpful. Meanwhile I was trying to create the table using graphic interface while expecting the answers for my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Gt_R It's cool. If my answer helped, upvote it and accept it. Honestly, it's faster to script it than do it through the designer. =)

Answer (score 3):

> The schema that will be used when schema is omitted will be the
>   default schema of the database user. Therefore, for creating table
>   without specifying schema, you'd have to set that database user's
>   default schema to dbo.

In your case try running:

```
CREATE TABLE [schemaname].[tableName](...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- Create the Suppliers table
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
    SupplierID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CompanyName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ContactNumber VARCHAR(20),
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Create the FoodTypes table
CREATE TABLE FoodTypes (
    FoodTypeID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FoodTypeName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ExpiryDate DATE NOT NULL
);

-- Create the AnimalCategories table
CREATE TABLE AnimalCategories (
    CategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CategoryName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the PetTypes table
CREATE TABLE PetTypes (
    PetTypeID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PetTypeName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CategoryID INT,
    StockLevel INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES AnimalCategories(CategoryID)
);

-- Create the FoodAllocation table
CREATE TABLE FoodAllocation (
    AllocationID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FoodTypeID INT,
    CategoryID INT,
    Quantity DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL,
    Unit VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (FoodTypeID) REFERENCES FoodTypes(FoodTypeID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES AnimalCategories(CategoryID)
);

-- Sample data for Suppliers
INSERT INTO Suppliers (CompanyName, ContactNumber, EmailAddress)
VALUES
    ('Veggie Land', '123-456-7890', 'veggie@land.com'),
    ('Premier Seed Suppliers', '987-654-3210', 'premier@seedsuppliers.com');

-- Sample data for FoodTypes
INSERT INTO FoodTypes (FoodTypeName, ExpiryDate)
VALUES
    ('Vegetables', '2023-12-31'),
    ('Seeds', '2023-12-31');

-- Sample data for AnimalCategories
INSERT INTO AnimalCategories (CategoryName)
VALUES
    ('Mammals'),
    ('Birds');

-- Sample data for PetTypes
INSERT INTO PetTypes (PetTypeName, CategoryID, StockLevel)
VALUES
    ('Dog', 1, 10),
    ('Cat', 1, 20),
    ('Parrot', 2, 40);

-- Sample data for FoodAllocation
INSERT INTO FoodAllocation (FoodTypeID, CategoryID, Quantity, Unit)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 8.5, 'kg'),
    (2, 2, 8.5, 'kg');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?